# accessing to file after upload by fabric

Tags: nginx, webserver, devops, nginx-config, system-administration

I used This code to deploy the file into server
``
`def do_deploy(archive_path):
"""
deploy archive the web servers
"""

```
if not exists(archive_path):
    return False

try:
    put(archive_path, '/tmp/')

    file = archive_path.split('/')[-1]
    file_without_ext = file.split('.')[0]

    run('mkdir -p /data/web_static/releases/{}/'.format(file_without_ext))

    run('tar -xzf /tmp/{} -C \
            /data/web_static/releases/{}'.format(file, file_without_ext))

    run('rm /tmp/{}'.format(file))

    run('mv /data/web_static/releases/{}/web_static/* \
            /data/web_static/releases/{}/'.format(
                file_without_ext, file_without_ext))

    run('rm -rf /data/web_static/releases/{}/web_static'.format(
        file_without_ext))`your text`

    run('rm /data/web_static/current')

    run('ln -sf /data/web_static/releases/{} \
            /data/web_static/current'.format(file_without_ext))

    return True

except:
    return False`
```

``

and Files its upload correctly and I update the nginx file in sites-availabel/default by adding this command

```
`    location /hbnb_static {
    alias /data/web_static/current/;
    index index.html index.htm;}`
```

and When I try to access to the file like this curl 100.26.230.80/hbnb_static/0-index.html
it give me 404 not found
Althoud the file is present the correct path

Try to access to file in web server